# Best python/Django code generator?

Tags: python, html, django, generator

very quick question. I am wondering if there are any software Django software that generates python coding automatically. If there are any, please let me know.

Comment: generate code from what ? UML diagrams ??? , you don't like __django-admin startproject__

Comment: what is your use case, what do you want to do? That would make it easier to suggest a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of python code generators. Python is a dynamic language where you can do almost anything. Instead of relying on static code generators known from the Java world, I would argue that you can write a couple of equivalent Python lines in most cases which is way more convenient.

In case you are looking for a Python lexer/parser, try [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: Good advice but it's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 9):

Let's not run-off new pythonistas with snide remarks... maybe the OP had legitimate needs for code generation.

Try these:

[Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/)

[Cog](http://www.python.org/about/success/cog/)

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

have fun!

Comment: Appreciate this answer (even if pretty old by now). I'm fairly new to Python and as I'm coming from a recent Node/Angular background, I'm unfamiliar with the dev workflow in django/drf. Feels like `manage.py` should have more commands similar to `ng g`, but I guess that's what I need to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Django Builder... is really cool... upload a models.py file and it generates better models.py, plus CRUD view templates, API/serializers, admin.py, urls.py, even tests!

https://mmcardle.github.io/django_builder/#!/home

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have seen in Python for code generation is Python's `__metaclass__` feature.  For example, here is a simple metaclass to create readonly properties:

```
class ReadonlyProperties(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        props = attrs.get("props",[])
        if props:
            # generate property for each name in propnames
            def defineProperty(p):
                return property(lambda self: getattr(self, '_'+p))
            for p,_ in props:
                setattr(cls, p, defineProperty(p))

            # generate wrapper for __init__ to initialize property values
            if "__init__" in attrs:
                setattr(cls, "__orig_init__", attrs["__init__"])
            else:
                setattr(cls, "__orig_init__", None)
            def new__init__fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.__orig_init__:
                    self.__orig_init__(*args)
                for p,pdefault in props:
                    if p in kwargs:
                        setattr(self, '_'+p, kwargs[p])
                    else:
                        setattr(self, '_'+p, pdefault)
            setattr(cls, "__init__", new__init__fn)

            # generate __str__ function
            def __repr__fn(self):
                return "%s(%s)" % (name, ','.join("%s=%s" % (p,getattr(self,p)) for p,_ in props))
            setattr(cls, "__repr__", __repr__fn)

            # don't need this class property any more
            delattr(cls, "props")
```

Now here is the metaclass in action:

```
class Coord3D(object):
    __metaclass__ = ReadonlyProperties
    props = [('x',0), ('y',0), ('z',0)]

pt = Coord3D(x=100, y=200)
print repr(pt)
print pt.x
print [n for n in dir(pt) if not n.startswith('__')]
```

Prints:

```
Coord3D(x=100,y=200,z=0)
100
['_x', '_y', '_z', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Assigning to `pt.x` will raise an AttributeError, since this is a readonly property.